# Позиционирование текста в адаптивном блоке

Tags: html, css, responsive

Есть блок с текстом. Мне нужно чтобы текст в нем чуть левее чем есть у меня и в адаптивной версии чтобы не выезжал за рамки. Я написал так:

```css
.sliderr__item .slid { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
/*END*/

.sliderr {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.sliderr__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
  /* ADDED: */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sliderr__item {
  flex: 0 0 50%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderr"><br>
   <div class="sliderr__wrapper">
      <div class="sliderr__item" style="border: 1px solid #DCE2EC;">
          <div style="height: 250px;" class="slid">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum</p><br>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum<br> 
              <span>Lorem Ipsum</span></p>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum<span>21.08.2018</span></p>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Но у меня есть ошибка где-то, не могу понять где. Подскажите как сделать текст адаптивным и чуть левее в комп версии.

Comment: Уберите центрирование, а `.slid` задайте `margin-left: XXXpx`, в адаптивной версии поменяйте эти XXXpx на необходимое кол-во %

Comment: @DaemonHK а в адаптивной версии как задать это кол-во %? `.slider-item {margin-left 10%}`. Так?

Comment: угу, только двоеточие не забудьте)

Comment: @DaemonHK дело в том что мне нужно прижать его к левой стороне, пишу `margin-left: 0` не помогает. в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `Уберите центрирование` - то бишь у `.sliderr__item .slid` убрать `text-align: center; align-items: center;`

Comment: @DaemonHK убрал. и вместо этого прописал left, но все равно не работает

Comment: `align-items: end;`

Comment: @DaemonHK не получается. не понимаю в чем проблема. все равно спасибо

Comment: Покажите код, который вы пишите для адаптивной версии

Comment: @DaemonHK обновил вопрос. только я там сейчас убрал `align-items`

Comment: У вас центрирования нет сейчас, отступ слева регулируется через `margin-left`. Меняйте его по необходимости при уменьшении разрешения.